# Too much database load when multiple instances refresh cache from DB at scheduled time

Tags: database, web-services, caching, load, continuous-deployment

There are 3000 instances of a service running to serve the trafffic. On midnight a job is scheduled in which each of these instances have to refresh their Local cache from database.
Since this results in huge number of db connections, DB load increases a lot. DB coordinator is asking to improve this situation. How to improve this situation.